# Securely transferring data from Postgres to Amazon S3 using WAL-E

Tags: postgresql, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wal-e

I want to use WAL-E to backup my PostgreSQL data to Amazon S3. I am trying to determine if the data is encrypted in transit from Postgres to S3 using SSL/TLS but the documentation is not entirely clear on this point. I see WAL-E uses boto library and I believe by default it uses SSL/TLS but can anybody confirm or tell me how to configure WAL-E to ensure it does use SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is the default, but you can manually specify the S3 endpoint to force the protocol.

https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e#manually-specifying-the-s3-endpoint

> The format is that of:
>
> protocol+convention://hostname:port Where valid protocols are http and
>   https, and conventions are path, virtualhost, and subdomain.
>
> Example:
>
> Turns off encryption and specifies us-west-1 endpoint.

```
WALE_S3_ENDPOINT=http+path://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com:80
```

> For radosgw.

```
WALE_S3_ENDPOINT=http+path://hostname
```

> As seen when using Deis, which uses radosgw.

```
WALE_S3_ENDPOINT=http+path://deis-store-gateway:8888
```

Comment: If you have timeout issues - eg connection reset by peer and you are using an S3 region outside the us you need to specify the endpoint like: WALE_S3_ENDPOINT=https+path://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443